# Анимация "выезжаения" строк таблицы JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, анимация

Хочу сделать плавное, вертикальное "выезжание" строк из шапки таблицы. Нужно что-то похожее на анимацию из [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) – **slideInDown** (только чтобы это анимация была из под шапки таблицы). Как это лучше сделать на JQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tbody td').show("drop", 1000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j9tn8qea/

Answer (score 2):

Ну как-то так и сделать:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tbody td').slideDown('slow');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j9tn8qea/2/

Comment: это не совсем то. Необходимо такое: http://savepic.ru/8442694.gif

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете осуществить и реализовать свою анимацию

```
 // Произведем изменение нескольких css-величин в ходе одной анимации.
$("#go").click(function(){
  $("#block").animate({ 
    width: "70%",         // ширина станет 70%
    opacity: 0.4,         // прозрачность будет 40%
    marginLeft: "0.6in",  // отступ от левого края элемента станет равным 6 дюймам
    fontSize: "3em",      // размер шрифта увеличится в 3 раза
    borderWidth: "10px"   // толщина рамки станет 10 пикселей
  }, 1500);               // анимация будет происходить 1,5 секунды
});
```

Или воспользоватся встроеными функциями анимации , например

```
.slideDown([duration],[easing],[callback]) .slideUp([duration],[easing],[callback])
```

С помощью этих функций можно показывать и скрывать выбранные элементы на странице, за счет плавного разворачивания и сворачивания.